# How do you get the namespace of a playground?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

In a standard Xcode project, you can use, for example, this pattern, where `Module` is the name of the module in which you're working:

```
protocol Protocol {}
struct Struct<Protocol: Module.Protocol> {}
```

How do you do that when you're just using a playground?